# Yii2 записывает в БД пустые значения

Tags: php, yii2

Мне нужно записать данные в базу данных. Yii2 записывает в базу данных пустые значения. Почему?

Вот контроллер:

```
public function actionEntry()
{
    $model = new EntryForm();

    if (isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) > 0)
    {
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post('EntryForm');
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($post['name']);exit;
        $model->load($post);
        $post = array(
          'name' => $post['name'],
            'text' => $post['text'],
        );
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($post);exit;
        $model->attributes = $post;
        $model->save();
        if ($model->save()) {
            echo "Данные успешно записались";
        } else {
            echo "Данные не записались";
        }
        //return $this->render('entry-confirm');
    }
    else
    {
        // либо страница отображается первый раз, либо есть ошибка в данных
        return $this->render('insert', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Вот моделька

```
public $name;
public $text;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'text'], 'required'],
    ];
}

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'dictionary';
}
```

Comment: Я что-то не помню: атрибуты (поля) name и text вообще нужны? Попробуйте удалить. :)

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не записывается? То что приходит из поста, или любые ваши попытки приводит к пустой записи? Есть ли ошибки что отображает что записывает? Сейчас все выглядит странно, метод load ничего не сделает с вашей переменной, потому что так не работает, присвоение атрибутам массива перепишет все то что пытается сделать load? и вообще проверяется массив пост потом пытаеться получить массив из поста, и не факт что он там есть

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос по другому.

Вот контроллер

```
public function actionEntry()
{
    $model = new EntryForm();

    if (isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST) > 0)
    {
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post('EntryForm');
        $model->load($post);
        $post = array(
          'name' => $post['name'],
            'text' => $post['text'],
        );
        $inser_bd = $model->my_query($post);
        if($inser_bd == true)
        {
            echo "Данные успешно добавлены";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Не удалось записать в бд";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // либо страница отображается первый раз, либо есть ошибка в данных
        return $this->render('insert', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Вот модель:

```
public $name;
public $text;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'text'], 'required'],
    ];
}

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'dictionary';
}

public function my_query($post)
{
    \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
        ->insert('dictionary', [
            'name' => $post['name'],
            'text' => $post['text'],
        ])->execute();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Гм. Ну это немасштабируемый костыль, а не решение.